# kentico error. Source FiftyOne Degrees

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to export from my dev site, and it's failing. The event log shows me this. Is FiftyOne Degrees one of the sample sites?

> EventID: 19797
>
> EventType: W
>
> EventTime: 2/2/2017 8:57:20 AM
>
> Source: FiftyOne Degrees
>
> EventCode: MissingDeviceData
>
> UserID: 53
>
> UserName: administrator
>
> IPAddress: 192.168.10.28
>
> EventDescription: Could not load the devices data package.
>
> EventUrl: /admin/cmsadministration.aspx
>
> EventMachineName: DEV2-CMSWEB
>
> EventUserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76
>   Safari/537.36
>
> EventUrlReferrer:
>   http://dev.knowledgefirstfinancial.ca/admin/cmsadministration.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I dug further, and found a web.config. From here: https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/developing-websites-for-mobile-devices/configuring-mobile-development

add `<add key="CMSEnable51D" value="false" />` to

No more log errors.

Answer (score 2):

FiftyOne Degrees is a feature for device detection within Kentico.  A few things you can check are:

1. Make sure you have device detection turned off. Settings>Integration>51Degrees
2. Make sure you have device profiles turned off. Settings>Content>Content Management. Not a guarantee gut helps if you're not using it.
3. Make sure you have the devices.xml file in the \App_Data\CMSModules\DeviceProfile directory.  By default there are some values in there and it might be empty or have invalid xml in your case.

There could be other items to look at but these are the ones that stick out initially.

Comment: Thanks. I had found then 51degeress.mobi setting. I'm gonig to compaire everything to my local and qa enviroments which are fine. Knock on wood. Cheers!

Comment: And i can't disable device detection within the 51Degrees.mobi section.

Comment: All thats right, you're still on v7 right?  So in this case you'd need to set the web.config key vs. doing it within the UI.  `<add key="CMSEnable51D" value="false" />`

Comment: No it's 9. All the other environments are fine, so not sure what broke dev. i'm working another issue, but that's a new question.